# Gmail API request to return emails sent from specific email address not working correctly

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I have the following code that I'm using to retrieve the most recent 25 emails sent from a particular user:

```
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(googleClientID, googleClientSecret, '');
oauth2Client.setCredentials(token);
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
var contact_email = 'some_person@email.com';

gmail.users.messages.list({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    userId: 'me',
    q: 'from:' + contact_email + '',
    maxResults: 25
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        response = [];
    } else {
        response = data.messages;
        console.log('response = ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that `response` always returns the most recent 25 emails, regardless of who the sender was. I only want the most recent 25 email from a particular user. I thought the `q` property would provide the proper filter for my request, but apparently not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should work. I'm not to familiar with the nodejs client library. Have you tried `url-encoding` the query yourself? `'from:some_person@email.com'` => `'from%3Asome_person%40email.com'`

Comment: Is there any verbose logging you could enable so as to inspect the raw query and response?